# how to fix the dependency issues on centos while installing "Development Tools"

Tags: centos, oci8

i ran this command

```
 yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

that gave these dependency issues do i need to add repo's to yum list?

```
Error: Package: git-1.7.10.2-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: subversion-1.6.13-0.1.el5.rf.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: libneon.so.25()(64bit)
Error: Package: subversion-1.6.13-0.1.el5.rf.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
           Installed: python-2.6.6-37.el6_4.x86_64 (@updates)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-51.el6.x86_64 (base)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python-2.6.6-52.el6.x86_64 (updates)
               python(abi) = 2.6
Error: Package: perl-Git-1.7.10.2-1.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Try to remove `python` first. and then `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`. Since it requires lower version of python.

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20044/package-git-1-7-6-1-1-el5-rf-i386-rpmforge-requires-libcurl-so-3/125357

Answer (score 0):

Webtatic doesn't support Git for RHEL/CentOS 6, however the way you're using the old Webtatic 5 repository suggests you've changed the /etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic.repo to always be enabled.

If you turn that off, you can install RHEL/CentOS 6's base git version, which is 1.7.1.

vi /etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic.repo

```
...
enable=0
```

Alternatively you can disable it temporarily for the current yum command:

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools" --disablerepo=webtatic
```

Comment: You should also be aware nothing in the Webtatic 5 repository is intended to be used on RHEL/CentOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below command which worked for me.

```
yum clean all
rm -rf /var/cache/yum
yum update
```